# integer comparison shows no output, why?

Tags: java

```
 int a=10, b=5;
    if(a>b)
    {
    if(b>5)
    System.out.println("b is:"+b);
     }
   else
    System.out.println("a is:"+a");
}
```

This code shows no output when running, why?

Comment: Because `5>5` is `false`. What did you expect?

Comment: Because your `else` is related to your first `if` and a is greater than b.

Comment: If you fix up you formatting it will be easier to read and it will be more obvious to you what this happens.  I suggest you use the formatter in your IDE as this will show you the layout your code has, not what you think it should have.

Answer (score 6):

Your snippet annotated:

```
int a=10, b=5;

if(a>b) // is true (10>5)
{
    if(b>5) // is false (5>5)
        System.out.println("b is:"+b);
    // no else case, so does nothing
}
else // never gets here
    System.out.println("a is:"+a");
} // unmatched bracket
```

Make sure there’s no syntax errors in your full code (like unmatched brackets) and that there’s always an else case, be it for development purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

That's **dangling else ambiguity**. You are matching wrong if clause with the else clause? It's a common error.

This is often due to poor formatting.

That's your code:

```
int a=10, b=5;
if(a>b)
{
if(b>5)
System.out.println("b is:"+b);
 }
else
System.out.println("a is:"+a");
}
```

That's a properly formatted code:

```
int a=10, b=5;
if(a>b)
{
   if(b>5)
      System.out.println("b is:"+b);
}
else
   System.out.println("a is:"+a");
}
```

See how each statement is indented. It's clear that the `else` clause is associated with the outer `if`. But, in your code it's hard to see.

Your IDE can properly format the code for you. If you are using Eclipse, for example, you can select your code and press `Ctrl + I` to format your code.

Comment: ＋１  calling the [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem by name.

Answer (score 0):

`if(a>b)` = `true` | No output

`if(b>5)` = `false` | No output (Reason: 5 is not greater than 5)

`else` block is not being executed

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows no output because a > b but b = 5, not greater than. To solve this, change `if(b>5)` to `if(b>=5)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another case where reformatting makes the question so much clearer.

```
    int a=10, b=5;
    if(a>b) { // 'true' - This block is executed
        if(b>5) // 5 is not greater than 5, it's equal, so this isn't executed
            System.out.println("b is:"+b);
    } else { // This is not executed
        System.out.println("a is:"+a);
    }
```

When a bug gets confusing just take the program step by step and think as the compiler would. Also, I'd recommend forming a full block with `{ braces }` for an `else` statement if you used braces for the `if` statement, it makes things tie together nicer and it's easier to read. Making sure things are indented properly also makes things easier to understand. Readability is important!

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=10, b=5;
if(a>b)
{
   if(b>5)
   System.out.println("b is:"+b);
}
else
   System.out.println("a is:"+a");}
```

In your code above In first if you are checking (a>b) i.e (10>5) the condition is true so execution of block inside first if is started.
In your second if condition (b>5) i.e (5>5) condition is false. So it terminates the program hence it doesn't displaying anything.
For better understanding I edit your code as below:

```
int a=10,b=5;
if(a>b)          // This condition is true so this if block executed
{
      if(b>5)    // this is false so this block won't execute.
      {
          System.out.println("b is :"+b);
      }
}
else  // Alredy first if executed because true condition so this also not executing
{
      System.out.println("a is :"+a);               
}
// Thats why you don't get any output in this program.
```